# Find a max sub-array in array

Tags: java

I am trying to find a sub-array in array `{-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3}` where the sum of the values is the maximum and print this array out. The result should be `[4, -1, -2, 1, 5]`. But in my case the result is `[-2, 1, 5]`, that is wrong

```
 static String maxSubArraySum(int[] a, int size)
{
    int max_so_far = a[0];
    int curr_max = a[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        curr_max = Math.max(a[i], curr_max+a[i]);
        max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, curr_max);
    }

    int [] res = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, curr_max, max_so_far);
    return Arrays.toString(res);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a[] = {-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3};
    int n = a.length;
    String arr = maxSubArraySum(a, n);
    System.out.println("Result is " + arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the indices to specify the range, not the real values of the array.
Also, copyOfRange range is from `first` element to `last+1`

You could do this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class lol{

    static String maxSubArraySum(int[] a, int size)
    {
        int max_so_far = a[0];
        int curr_max = a[0];
        int curr_max_idx = 0;
        int max_so_far_idx = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            curr_max = Math.max(a[i], curr_max+a[i]);
            if(curr_max==a[i]){
                curr_max_idx = i;
            }
            max_so_far = Math.max(max_so_far, curr_max);
            // i+1 to end at last + 1
            if(max_so_far==curr_max){
                max_so_far_idx = i + 1;
            }
        }
        int [] res = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, curr_max_idx, max_so_far_idx);
        return Arrays.toString(res);
    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a[] = {-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3};
        int n = a.length;
        String arr = maxSubArraySum(a, n);
        System.out.println("Result is " + arr);
    }
}
```

or instead of `Math.max()` function, just use if statements and update `curr_max` and its index `curr_max_idx`